# Ubuntu WiFi says connected, but no internet access

Tags: networking, internet, 15.10

I will be using the internet fine, then it will stop, other devices can continue to use the internet fine. Ubuntu 15.10 says that it is connected. When disconnecting then reconnecting it won't connect. Sometimes it will connect to other networks other times it won't (even the same network). I have tried

```
sudo ifconfig wlp8s0 down
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

To no avail. A temporary fix is a restart of computer.